# Returning a function from an object breaks instanceof

Tags: javascript, oop

This little gem is giving me a bit of a headache. Let's say I create an object that returns a function, like this:

```
function Bar(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
    var that = this;
    return function() {
        this.prop = that.prop;
    }
}

var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar instanceof Bar)​;
```

`Bar()` returns a function, as you can see. Now, `Bar() instanceof Bar` returns false, which isn't what I want. How do I check to see if a `new Bar()` is an instance of `Bar`? Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand what you're trying to do. `new foo.bar()` will never be an `instanceof foo`, it's an `instanceof foo.bar`.

Comment: "The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). I don't see why you expect bar() to be an instance of foo.bar.

Comment: Also, returning an object from a constructor will use the returned object instead of instantiating a new object of that type.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your variable names. Did you mean `new test.bar()` or `(new foo).bar()`? Or what does `new foo.bar()` mean? `foo` has no property `bar`. In any case, since `bar()` returns a *function*, it is never an instance of `test.bar`... which overall problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @FelixKling: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Let me see if I can provide a clearer code example to show my problem.

Comment: I've provided a clearer code example, hopefully it should explain my problem better.

Comment: It's not possible, since you simply don't return an instance of `Bar`. You return a new function... if you could create a function that inherits from `Bar`, then it would work, but afaik this is not possible (yet, who knows what will come in future ES versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning *any* object from a constructor will use that object instead of returning an instance automatically generated by the constructor. It's a bit abstract, so here's an example to show my point:

```
function Foo() {}
function Bar() {
    return new Foo();
}
f = new Foo();
console.log(f instanceof Foo); //true
b = new Bar();
console.log(b instanceof Bar); //false
console.log(b instanceof Foo); //true
```

Everything in JavaScript is an object, including functions, so the fact that your `foo.bar` function returns a function means that when you call `new foo.bar()` you're going to receive the function returned by `foo.bar` instead of a new `foo.bar` instance.

---

While I'm not 100% certain of what you're trying to do exactly, you *can* check whether a function is being called as an object initializer or as a function simply by using `instanceof` on the context. This pattern is often used for forcing object initialization:

```
function Foo(...arguments...) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
        return new Foo(...arguments...);
    }
    //do stuff
}
```

This allows `Foo` to be called as a function and still return a new `Foo` instance:

```
a = new Foo(); //a instanceof Foo
b = Foo(); //b instanceof Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why you'd want to do what you are doing but I see what the issue is.

In the scope of 'test', this.bar is the function bar(prop) rather than the function returned as a result of executing this function, if that makes sense. However, new this.bar('hi') will be first executing bar('hi'), which returns an anonymous function that then acts as the constructor.

In other words, you are comparing an instance created from the anonymous function with a different function so instanceof is correctly returning false.

The following logs 'true' but may not be what you are looking for:

```
function foo() {
    this.test = function() {
        var cls = this.bar('hi');
        console.log(new cls() instanceof cls);
    };

    this.bar = function bar(prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
        var that = this;
        return function() {
            this.prop = that.prop;
        }
    }
}

var test = new foo();
test.test();
```

Comment: This is still useful, howard10. I think it may in fact solve my problem.